# Which exception should be thrown for an invalid file name?

Tags: .net, exception

I have a method which accepts a filename as a parameter, all filenames should end with '.csv'. Which exception should I throw if a filename that does not end with .csv is passed?

Or should I take a different approach?

Comment: What happens if a user has a `*.txt` file in comma-separated-values format? For an arbitrary application, the *expected behavior* in this case is allowing explicit selection of the file via the "All Files" filter in the `FileDialog`, or a full filename input with extension.

Comment: I agree with using ArgumentOutOfRangeException.  If the file object's type/extension is being validated at a later point (or argument validation isn't applicable), sometimes I've used FileFormatException to indicate that the file is the wrong type of file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28VS.80%29.aspx) - What you're describing is in line with an out of range exception:

> The exception that is thrown when the
>   value of an argument is outside the
>   allowable range of values as defined
>   by the invoked method.

[ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28VS.80%29.aspx) is used to validate the *characters* in the path string not the file type.

> The path parameter is a zero-length
>   string, contains only white space, or
>   contains one or more invalid
>   characters.

IMHO the path validation fall-through chart looks like this:

- Input path is null =
  [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx)
- Invalid characters in the path =
  [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- File doesn't exist =
  [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx)
- File isn't the right type =
  [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- Permissions problem =
  [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx)
- File system doesn't support this
  operation =  [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx)
- System read error = [IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx)

If that's not descriptive enough for you then create your own exception class:

```
public class InvalidFileTypeException : System.IO.IOException
{
    public InvalidFileTypeException(string path, string acceptedTypeMask) 
    {
        this.Message = string.Format(
            "File type '{0}' does not fall within the expected range: '{1}'", 
            path, 
            acceptedTypeMask);
    }
}
```

...

```
throw new InvalidFileTypeException("foo.txt", "*.csv");
```

Comment: +1, agreed - as the documentation for `ArgumentException` states, "The primary derived classes of `ArgumentException` are  `ArgumentNullException` and  `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. These derived classes should be used instead of `ArgumentException`, except in situations where neither of the derived classes is acceptable."

Answer (score 11):

ArgumentException would fit the bill IMO.

Answer (score 10):

I'd probably use [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(VS.80).aspx), as it's "The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid"

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation of an existing IO method in the Framework. It describes the exceptions generated by a method. For example, check [StreamWriter.StreamWriter(String, Boolean, Encoding, Int32) Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf7ab94(VS.85).aspx) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf7ab94(VS.85).aspx. The exception I suggest you use, to remain consistent, is **IOException**. You can then add a custom message that describes the particulars.

IOException - path includes an incorrect or invalid syntax for file name, directory name, or volume label syntax.

In your case, the file extension is incorrect, so tell the user, as in `Throw New IOException("Invalid file extension.")`.

I would leave **ArgumentException** as described in the documentation, *path is an empty string ("").*"

See [Choosing the Right Type of Exception to Throw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229021.aspx) at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229021.aspx.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not too happy with how the framework handles this, but if you want to be consistent with the Stream classes it may be a good idea to do this (assuming the method in question is actually related to IO)

Comment: Agreed, but after I got use to the IO exceptions, I don't mind it too much. One benefit of leaving ArgumentException as defined would allow for easy debugging when filename is really "".

Comment: No, an incorrect (but valid) extension isn't an IOExcpetion. It's a broken constraint at this level.

Comment: Good point. Yet...I am more trying to point the developer to look at existing documentation for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

`System.ArgumentException` appears appropriate, either directly or as a base class for your exception.

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating your own `InvalidFilenameException`? For example:

```
public class InvalidFilenameException : Exception
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public InvalidFilenameException(string message, string invalidFilename)
        :base(message)
    {
        Filename = invalidFilename;
    }
}
```

Comment: The more code you write, the more potential for bugs, the more time it takes, the more decisions have to be made. Unless there is a specific need for a custom exception, it is better to avoid them.

Comment: Well, of course. But if I find it clearer to create your own Exception if you can't really find anyone that really fits. Like the suggested IOException. Is it really an IOException? I would probably use ArgumentException, suggested by others here. But just thought I could bring an alternative.

Comment: True. Henk Holterman makes a good point. It is kind of hard to make a suggestion because the question is vague. That is why I try to get the developer to look at existing documentation for guidance.

Comment: And that is a very good idea. The problem is when you forget that you have alternatives to what exists there. At least I have often found myself trying to use stuff in the framework that hasn't quiiite fit what I needed it to, and tried to sort of twist it into what I need. But then I realize what I am doing, and remember that, hey, why don't I just inherit from something, or from scratch, and make my own thing that would actually be what I want, instead of kiiind of what I want.