# How to validate a path string?

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-5

Is there any function available to validate a path string?

Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0 says that "All `Path` members that take a path as an argment throw an ArgumentException if they detect invalid path characters."

Should this throw an exception?

```
PS C:\src\t> [Io.Path]::GetFullPath('C:\sr<|c\t')
C:\sr<|c\t
PS C:\src\t> dotnet --version
5.0.301
PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.0
```

Comment: You can abuse `System.Uri.TryParse`. If it returns true, then path is valid

Comment: if ((Test-Path -Path $yourPath) -eq $false) {
  Write-Output "Path is invalid";
  return;  
 }

Comment: `Test-Path $path -IsValid` looks promising, but appears to be broken as it returns `$true` for `C:\sr<|c\t`.

Comment: Interestingly, `Test-Path 'C:\sr<|c\t' -IsValid` returns `$false` on PS 5.1, as expected. It appears to be broken in PS 7.x only.

Comment: On PS 5.1 `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath('C:\sr<|c\t')` does throw an exception about invalid characters.

Comment: @JL0PD, I have not yet found `System.Uri.TryParse`. Could you point me to some Microsoft documentation about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since apparently the behavior changed dramatically since PS version 5.1, you may have to rely on a test function of your own..

Perhaps something like

```
function Test-IsValidPath {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path,
        [switch]$MustExist
    )
    # test for invalid characters
    if ($Path.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars()) -ge 0) { return $false }
    # if the path should exist
    if ($MustExist) { return (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Path) }
    $true
}

Test-IsValidPath 'C:\sr<|c\t'  # --> False
```

Of course, you can also create something that would throw exceptions.. For that, please see [Which exception should be thrown for an invalid file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421577/9898643)

Comment: Checking for invalid path characters is a good idea, @Theo. But, I wonder if there are more things to consider? What about length of the path? Will this work if the string is a Unicode transformation format? Are there any other opportunities for failure?

Comment: @lit Hmm.. good points. This obviously needs some work to handle stuff like that.

Comment: That is why I believe this is work that Microsoft should deliver. Also, does or could this have meaning for "paths" other than `FileSystem` providers? Registry paths?

Comment: @lit I agree, but reading the final answer on [github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16465)
  _"This issue has been marked as by-design"_ I don't think it is going to be fixed..

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

We have **ValidateScript** command to validate the folder path inside the powershell function parameter like below:

```
function Validate-Path{
   param(
      [parameter(Mandatory)]
      [String]$Path
   )
   if(Test-Path $Path) {Write-Output "Path is valid"}
   else{Write-Output "Path is invalid"}
}
```

Give this code in the PowerShell and press enter.
And type `Validate-Path -Path <give-your-folder-path>` and press enter which shows valid or invalid path.

I have executed this to validate my folder path in PowerShell:
Look at this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI8JV.png)

**Method 2:**

I also tested the [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) comment and it worked fine:

```
PS C:\Users\saiha> Test-Path "C:\Users\saiha\Documents"
True
PS C:\Users\saiha> Test-Path "C:\Users\saiha\Docs"
False
PS C:\Users\saiha>
```

***Also With the given path in a question tested with both the methods:***

```
PS C:\Users\saiha> Test-Path "C:\sr<|c\t"
Test-Path : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Path "C:\sr<|c\t"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\sr<|c\t:String) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

False
PS C:\Users\saiha> Test-Path "C:\src\t"
True
//User-Defined function
PS C:\Users\saiha> function Validate-Path{
>>    param(
>>       [parameter(Mandatory)]
>>       [String]$Path
>>    )
>>    if(Test-Path $Path) {Write-Output "Path is valid"}
>>    else{Write-Output "Path is invalid"}
>> }
PS C:\Users\saiha> Validate-Path -Path C:\src\t
Path is valid
PS C:\Users\saiha> Validate-Path -Path C:\sr<|c\t
c\t : The module 'c' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module c'.
At line:1 char:28
+ Validate-Path -Path C:\sr<|c\t
+                            ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c\t:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

PS C:\Users\saiha>
```

**Practical Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Rda.png

Correct me If I understood in a different.

In Method 1, I created a user-defined function and tested using it and in method 2, Test-Path is a native function. But both do the same checks and give the correct result.

Comment: This tests if the path exists. I think OP wants to test, whether the path is syntactically correct, even if it does not exist.

Comment: If it does not exists, it shows the path is invalid, that also tested by giving the improper path address

Comment: Only in PS 5. In PS 7.2.0 I don't get error message "Illegal characters in path".

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works on PowerShell Core. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16465

Comment: Yeah, Test-Path doesn't throw the exception here

Comment: If the posted answer helped, you may mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so can help other community members.